# How to translate such a function to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, translation

So in my [code](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudObserver/CloudObserverInstaller/htdocs/index.html?r=983) I used

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

I want to move to jQuery. How to translate such thing to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use this function, `function $(id)`. Use the jQuery function `$('#id')`. This function will return an object with bunch of jQuery methods.

Methods include  `remove()`, `hide()`, `toggle()`, etc., and the implementation is like `$('#id').hide()`, `$('#id').show()`, etc.

There are so many, many jQuery methods, that simplifies it in so many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$("#"+id)
```

That will return the element with the right ID.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you will need to include jQuery inside your page, and replace the following line:

`return document.getElementById(id);`

with this one:

`return $("#"+id);`

Comment: Oh no, don't make another `$` function, that's completely unneeded.

Comment: I'm not doing so, just answering his question.
and yes, I agree that he shouldn't use a function called $(id), but I didn't see his full code to assume that he can't use such function.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery selectors you can do the same thing very easily.

$("#" + id)

For more details:

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/